# sql to oder by current date

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, sap-ase

I am trying to roder a resultset based on Current date in Sybase ASE. I do not understand how to do that.

> select x,date1 from abc where x>y 
>   order by date1> current_date

How to use the current date in orderby clause?

Comment: Order by current date doesn't make much sense. I think you want `ORDER BY dateColumn DESC`

Comment: Are you trying to only see dates that are greater than the current date and the order by the date?  If so that really belongs in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, i got the requirements wrong. it makes sence to just sort in Desc or asc and then work with the data. sometimes I tend to forget basic things when i am too busy. Thank you all for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

not clear but i guess you want to do somemthing like below Query

```
  SELECT X,date1 from abc 
    where x>y 
    and date1 >current_Date --can use getdate() for current date 
    order by date1
```